# What word describes something that occurs every minute or second?

Tags: single-word-requests

Something that happens every hour can be called *hourly*. Something that occurs at a frequency of every week is called *weekly*. What word describes something that happens every minute? What about every second?

Comment: I suspect you won't improve on the phrases "once per minute" and "once per second". Although in some cases you might be able to use "at 1 Hz".

Comment: Also see *[Weekly, Daily, Hourly — Minutely…?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3091)* and *[Words for Frequencies Less Than an Hour](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235614)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such word currently in common use. You should simply say it happens *once every minute* or *once every second*.

Although *[minutely](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/minutely)* and *[secondly](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/secondly)* exist, they mean completely different things.

Comment: I like the note about "minutely" and "secondly", but could you add links to make it clear what they do mean?

Comment: Anecdata: as a software developer, I frequently hear _minutely_ (pronounced like "MINute" the unit of time, not "minUTE" the adjective) used in the sense of _once every minute_. Can't say the same for _secondly_, though.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to use expressions like:

> - one second intervals

and

> - 60-second intervals

[Ngram](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39778/why-does-gasoline-have-the-word-gas-in-it-if-its-never-gaseous) *one second intervals, 60-second intervals*

Comment: we should use `at` or `in` before `... intervals`?